# How to construct matrices whose orthogonal complement of the row space is spanned by a vector

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

This is an example problem, some of them use the complement to the Column space instead. My way of thinking was that since the complement of the row space is the null space of the matrix, I would make a matrix so that the matrix multiplied by the null space would equal 0. What would be the correct way of thinking for a problem like this?

Comment: So far, so good. You’re not asked to construct just any old matrix, though: you’re asked for one in reduced echelon form. That constrains many of the entries. As well, the null space is one-dimensional. What does this tell you about the number of pivots that the matrix must have?

Comment: 2 pivots, i figured this out, but how does this way thinking work if the null space was spanned by 2 or more vectors?